# Hidden development server

Tags: web, development

I have a development server, which I setup as a normal website but behind a standard Http Auth login which prevents anyone from getting in (normally).

How can I setup a server that would not be found unless its known by their developer and associates? To also prevent Google from potentially indexing anything, but also so the Auth isn't preventing third party sites from working (caching for example).

Would I use a different port number like 8080? What is a common setup for working live, but being stealthy.

Thanks

Comment: What are those "third party sites" you are talking about?

Comment: For example, if another site wants to cache an image from my site - it would be impossible to test since my site is preventing unauthorized requests.

Comment: By "cache" you mean hotlink?

Comment: No - meaning fetch a version of a resource to cache to their servers. I have a real situation, where the cart I use cache images for use in the cart & checkout page. So for this reason, images never showed up. Another example is Facebook share button will not work since Facebook cannot grab data from the page.

Answer (score 3):

Put the server on a private network and require connecting to a VPN in order to access it.

Comment: How would I setup something like this? I've accessed a VPN but never setup one up. Would it require a new server? Or could be handled on the same server?